# Connecting +/-4V signal to ADC in microcontroller

Tags: voltage, adc, current-transformer

I want to connect current transformer do the ADC input in microcontroller. The device have analog signal output (-4 to +4V) and ADC range is 0 to 3.3V
I have PCB according to the below scheme. Is the analog part ok?
I'm not experienced in analog electronics.

When I connect additional potentiometer to socket and change voltage in range (-4 to +4V) to simulate device, I measurement 0.8 do 2V on ADC input. How should I tune potentiometers on scheme to set correct voltage range?

[image]